# Why is it still printing

Tags: python, string, for-loop, split, extract

I have 2 txt files, one has extra lines. I would like to extract the extra lines only. It keeps printing everything. Why? I am saying if the first line of txt1 is not equal to the first line of txt 2 then print it.

```
import os, sys

htmlRub = ""

path = "./filter.txt"
if os.path.isfile(path):
    oFile = open(path)
    filter = oFile.read()
    oFile.close()
else:
    print("Filter file is missing")

path = "./database.txt" #The HTML code downloaded
if os.path.isfile(path):
    oFile = open(path)
    htmlRub = oFile.read() #The HTML code downloaded
    oFile.close()
else:
    print("Database file is missing")

filterData = filter.split("\n")
htmlData = htmlRub.split("\n") #The HTML code downloaded


for line in htmlData:
    for lineagain in filterData:
        if line != lineagain:
            print(line)
            break
        else:
            pass
            break
```

Comment: What do you intend the `pass` and `break` statements at the end of that double-for loop to do?

Comment: In your  last loop, the inner lopp will execute only once. You have break in both `if` and `else` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to remove all of the strings from htmlData that are in filterData.  I hope.

```
delta = [s for s in htmlData if s not in filterData]
for s in delta:
    print s
```

Your loop, as the comments state, is not doing what you think it is.
One loop format for the list comprehension would be:

```
for hline in htmlData:
    if hline not in filterData:
        print hline
```

Answer (score 1):

Christopher,

To keep your code mostly the same, it looks like you just need to change:

```
if line != lineagain:
    print(line)
else:
    pass
    break
```

to:

```
if line != lineagain:
    print(line)
else:
    continue
```

robert_x44's answer is a bit more "Pythonic", as it were.

Comment: Thankyou, but my code was failing, no matter what I wrote in 48hrs it would print everything. my code is a fail.